# Ellipsis not working correctly in Firefox for pseudo element

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to insert a line after some text but once it reaches max-width(170px) i want to show ellipsis.

but in firefox everytime it showing ellipsis which I don't want.

I want to work same in firefox the way its working in chrome and IE.

```css
div {
  max-width: 170px;
  background-color: #c7bdbd;
}

h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h1>Longer Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Firefox is not able to interpret the width as 100% properly and hence shows ellipse always. To check this try giving an explicit width to the pseudo class

Comment: The ::after is simply too large to fit in the h1 because of its width. The negative right margin notwithstanding. Can you provide an example that shows why the ::after is needed at all? Removing it (or some properties of it like the `display` or the `width`) makes the snippet work as expected.

Comment: @MrLister the after pseudo element was needed to display line after text.

Comment: @Mahi What line? I think it all hangs on that. How wide is it, does it need to be in an inline-block or can it simply be inline, etc.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal if i give width to pseudo element then the line width will be same for long or short text. i mean if i have long text i have to show less line and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolute position the pseudo element. I think the issue is that the ellipsis style is firefox is treating the inline pseudo element as text and triggering the ellipsis, however it is then appending the ellipsis to the actual text. Applying absolute position to the pseudo element will stop this behavior.

UPDATE: After reading about this further it is actually a bug in chrome. Firefox is correctly interpreting the specification for `overflow:ellipsis;`.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1346436

```css
div {
  max-width: 170px;
  background-color: #c7bdbd;
}

h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position:relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h1>Longer Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you are my hero . Thanks :)

Comment: bdw i thought its bug in firefox :P

Comment: So did I, but all inline elements including pseudo elements with `overflow:ellipsis;` should trigger the ellipsis when it overflows the parent. The issue is that the pseudo element has no content so there is nothing for the ellipsis to be appended to.